# Встроить интерпретатор Python в файлы приложения

Tags: python, exe

Мне необходимо сделать приложение независимым от наличия python-а на компьютере пользователя, сохранив при этом максимальную открытость кода. То, что я пока придумал, это впихнуть интерпретатор целиком в отдельную подпапку приложения и указал в основном скрипте путь туда. Однако, проведя тесты на других компьютерах, где Питона отродясь не было(своему я переименовывал корневую директорию, чтобы Windows его не нашёл) ничего не работает.
Использование "--exclude-module" в PyInstaller не помогло - происходят ошибки и вылеты, а из-за того, что основной код уже запакован, я не могу понять, почему. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.

Comment: А вы не рассматриваете вариант python-to-executable?

Comment: Главное - максимальная открытость кода. Тот же pyinstaller просто запихивает все модули в один файл, и об открытости не может идти и речи